# How to fix paths to background images while deploying vue app to gh-pages?

Tags: github-pages

I'm deploying my vue-app to gh-pages and facing a problem with loading background images.

Here is structure of my project

[image]

And [here](https://kiraburova.github.io/shelter/#/) link to my project on gh-pages live.
You can see that images from img tags are loading and also svg files are loading but background-images which are not svg are not (all my background-images are in img folder).

I can see in console what paths are messed up - they should be `static/img/footer.88ceaa2.png` but instead they are `static/css/static/img/footer.88ceaa2.png`

Should paths to backgrounds be different in my components or is it something in my config file? Any help will be much appreciated.

[Link to repo](https://github.com/KiraBurova/shelter/tree/master)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have same problem with Nuxt and there is a way to work around by binding style as inline

```
:style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + require('@/assets/imgs/assets/img/header.png') + ')' }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the new version of [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli).

**Install**:

```
$ npm install -g @vue/cli
--or--
$ yarn global add @vue/cli
```

**Create a new project:**

```
$ vue create my-project
```

cd into `my-project` and delete the `src` folder.
Copy your `src` folder from your project(shelder)
and paste it into `my-project` folder.

**Run the project**:

```
$ npm run serve
--or--
$ yarn serve
```

**Build**:

```
$ npm run build
--or--
$ yarn build
```